# How to plot an interpolating function from data showing the median values and the scatter around the medians

Tags: plotting, interpolation

I have a list of data points $x_{i}$, $y_{i,16}$, $y_{i,50}$, and $y_{i,84}$ where $y_{i}$ respectively correspond to $16th$, $50th$ and $84th$ percentiles value of the function at positions $x_{i}$. I would like to plot the data and then use the interpolating function (including its confidence interval) in subsequent lines of code (to be used inside other functions). I am not sure how to approach the problem in Mathematica.

Here are my data points:

```
MyData2 = {{1807952.4, 0.}, {2865411.4, 0.}, {4541371.1, 
    0.}, {7197588.2, 1.4524}, {11407409., 18.8968}, {18079524., 
    64.6294}, {28654115., 234.527}, {45413713., 1683.25}, {71975884., 
    1.64355*10^6}, {1.1407409*10^8, 1.17502*10^7}, {1.8079525*10^8, 
    1.94918*10^7}, {2.8654116*10^8, 2.66641*10^7}, {4.5413714*10^8, 
    3.86850*10^7}, {7.1975887*10^8, 5.74504*10^7}, {1.1407409*10^9, 
    9.94850*10^7}, {1.8079526*10^9, 2.30266*10^8}, {2.8654117*10^9, 
    5.61204*10^8}, {4.5413716*10^9, 9.74900*10^8}, {7.1975889*10^9, 
    1.42693*10^9}, {1.1407410*10^10, 1.73923*10^9}, {1.8079526*10^10, 
    1.83409*10^9}, {2.8654118*10^10, 2.14442*10^9}, {4.5413717*10^10, 
    1.55072*10^9}, {7.1975892*10^10, 1.26887*10^9}, {1.1407410*10^11, 
    9.89815*10^8}, {1.8079527*10^11, 8.42409*10^8}, {2.8654119*10^11, 
    3.67434*10^8}, {4.5413719*10^11, 5.15284*10^8}, {7.1975894*10^11, 
    0.}, {1.1407411*10^12, 0.}};
errorlow = {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 572.588, 96548.0, 
   5.71988*10^6, 1.52344*10^7, 2.02001*10^7, 3.13098*10^7, 
   4.76685*10^7, 8.08936*10^7, 1.44154*10^8, 2.48105*10^8, 
   2.30940*10^8, 2.45418*10^8, 2.01769*10^8, 2.28840*10^8, 
   2.95364*10^8, 2.98022*10^8, 1.71492*10^8, 4.93063*10^8, 0., 0.};
errorhigh = {282.782, 472.186, 587.986, 2283.55, 488366., 
   9.17766*10^6, 1.27044*10^7, 1.65682*10^7, 2.45337*10^7, 
   3.46505*10^7, 4.88848*10^7, 7.02281*10^7, 1.50805*10^8, 
   4.32480*10^8, 8.35527*10^8, 1.43467*10^9, 2.14970*10^9, 
   2.77410*10^9, 3.52198*10^9, 4.30402*10^9, 5.38495*10^9, 
   5.70328*10^9, 5.12281*10^9, 3.53019*10^9, 2.22876*10^9, 
   1.73264*10^9, 1.12033*10^9, 6.69324*10^8, 0., 0.};
```

Your help is greatly appreciated.

I have Mathematica 8.0.

Comment: @m_goldberg, thanks for the edit.

Comment: Do you mean the model fit? Making an interpolating function of this data is going to give crappy results.

Comment: I'd also like to point out that at some point, your upper bounds go lower than your best estimate, as per `ListPlot[{Transpose[{MyData[[All, 1]], errorhigh}], 
  Transpose[{MyData[[All, 1]], errorlow}], MyData}, PlotRange -> All, 
 Joined -> True, Filling -> {{1 -> {3}}, {3 -> {2}}}]`

Comment: @Feyre, these are really the correct data I have taken from a paper. Do you still see the issue you mentioned (after correcting some of my data)?

Comment: No, the new data corrects the issue. But still Interpolation is going to be very inaccurate for such a function, Actually, the model you've provided doesn't seem to go near the points, and fitting seems to get poor results, are you sure the form is correct?

Comment: Benjamin, I suspect that you will need to give an example of how you are going to use this "interpolating function (including its confidence interval) in subsequent lines of code" before an answer is possible.  Perhaps you could expand this question to describe what you are *really trying to do* in a broader context?